# Laravel 7 MySQL integrity constraint violation

Tags: mysql, join, eloquent, laravel-7

I'm trying to create a page whereupon clicking on a specific user will grab all information about them from two different MySQL tables. The common column that both tables have in common for each row is the id column in the Users table (matches the `userid` column in the `client_profiles` table).

**Controller**

```php
class ClientController extends Controller
{
    public function viewclient($id)
    {
        $client = DB::table('users')
            ->join('client_profiles', 'users.id', 'client_profiles.userid')
            ->having('id', '>', $id)
            ->get();

        return view('viewclient', compact('client'));
    }
}
```

**Error**

> Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in having clause is
> ambiguous (SQL: select * from `users` inner join `client_profiles` on
> `users`.`id` = `client_profiles`.`userid` having `id` > 2)

In my Blade file I have...

```
<input id="grid-first-name" type="text" value='{{ $client->userid }}'>
```

Comment: So, `id` is ambiguous. Which table's `id`? Dot it. Presumably with `users`. PS Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure it is **id > 2**  and not **id = 2**? Id is ambiguous so you have to dot it
`->having('users.id', '>', $id)`